# How do I add element to be printed using dataTable print button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I use [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) print button to print files. I'd like to add another `div` to be printed above or under the table.

I use this script in datatable to add some header

`title    : "This should be another element printed above the DataTable<br /><span id='txt-small' style='font-size:'12px !important;'>Dates : </span>",`

But, it's probably not the right method because I may add a complex header above the DataTable.

I also use `footer    : true,` to add something to print in `<tfoot>` but then again I may add a complex footer under the DataTable.

So, how do I add another element `div` or `table` to be printed above or under the DataTable when I print the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `customize` method:

```
{
  extend: 'print',
  title: ' ',
  message: ' ',
  customize: function(win) {
    $(win.document.body).append('<html elements here>'); //after the table
    $(win.document.body).prepend('<html elements here>'); //before the table
  }
},
```

Reference here : [Customisation of the print view window](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/customisation.html)